# Создание интерфейса - Drag And Drop

Tags: c#, winforms, интерфейс

Подскажите как реализовать интерфейс в котором будет реализован Drag And Drop для компонентов, наследуемых User Control'ами.

Либо каким простым способом можно перемещать User Control'ы по форме.

Пример стороннего кода:

```
public interface IDragable
{
    bool Hit(Point point);
    void Drag(Point offset);
    IDragable StartDrag(Point p);
    void EndDrag();
}
```

Comment: Как вы такой интерфейс предполагаете использовать? Покажите пример кода

Comment: Это вообще WPF или WinForms?

Comment: Это фрагмент кода для WinForms.

Comment: [Выполнение операции перетаскивания](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-performing-a-drag-and-drop-operation-in-windows-forms).

Answer (score 0):

Частичный ответ на вопрос, без использования интерфейса решил таким образом.

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
{
    NewPoint = mevent.Location;
    IsDragMode = true;
    base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
{
    IsDragMode = false;
    base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mevent)
{
    //если кнопка мыши нажата
    if (IsDragMode)
    {
        Point p = mevent.Location;
        //вычисляем разницу в координатах между положением курсора и "нулевой" точкой кнопки
        Point dp = new Point(p.X - NewPoint.X, p.Y - NewPoint.Y);
        Location = new Point(Location.X + dp.X, Location.Y + dp.Y);
    }
    base.OnMouseMove(mevent);
}
```